# Pointers to structs vs actual objects

Tags: c, struct

I am learning C and am playing around with the following example.

I don't fully understand why this works.

```
typedef struct
{
   char even;
   int length;   
} Square;

Square* square;

void make_square(void) {
   Square s;
   s.even = 1;
   s.length = 10;
   square = &s;
}

void print_square(void) {
   printf("even: %u\n", square->even);
   printf("size: %i\n", square->length);
}

int main() {
   make_square();
   print_square();
}
```

I would have assumed that this code is incorrect because we have the line `square=&s` which sets our global pointer `square` to point to an object that exists only within the function `make_square`.

So in theory I would have thought the correct thing to do would be `*square = s`. But this gives me a seg fault.

I'm wondering why the latter gives me a seg fault and if the posted way (code above) is also correct or just happens to work by chance.

**SOLVED** *Not enough rep to accept the correct answer*

I forgot to malloc space on the heap for the square first. So when I tried it the way I thought it should work I got a seg fault.

Comment: `*square = s` would only work if `square` were pointed at an actual struct (one that's still valid) first.  As for the way you have posted, you're right in thinking it only works by chance -- it *is* incorrect, for the reason you suspected... and you can't count on it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the dangers of C.  It isn't really working; you have a pointer to a square that was on the stack. What happens from here on out is going to cause problems! If you try to change the object, you will likely corrupt variables on the stack.  What you want to do is `malloc` a square and return it — but then you are responsible for freeing it later.

Comment: Thanks! I just figured this out too but you beat me to writing an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `Square s;` definition to `static Square s;` and everything will be ok. In your case it is working as side effect - in some cases it may not work, in other cases it will seem working. And generally, if you are using global variable `square` (which is not very good idea), why it is pointer to structure and not the real object of structure?

Comment: Everything will be OK... Until you want to make another square.

Comment: @Quentin We are discussing the example from the author, not theoretical situation.

Comment: This solution would solve a very specific problem though, and wouldn't help at all in the usual case. It is technically a solution, but you really should add a word on what `static` actually does, and when to actually use it.

Answer (score -2):

`*square = s;` is bad if `square` has `NULL`, which is the default value of global variable which isn't initialized explicitly.